# Removing nginx compilation

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, compilation

I have compiled nginx(1.13.6) on my ubuntu server by cloning and installing nginx from git. I want to recompile it with additional modules. When I try to remove nginx using:

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo rm -f -R /usr/local/nginx && rm -f /usr/local/sbin/nginx
```

I get the following output when `sudo service nginx status` is entered which shows that nginx has not been fully removed.

```
    ● nginx.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)

systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service:6] Unknown lvalue 'KillStop' in section 'Service'
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service:6] Unknown lvalue 'KillStop' in section 'Service'
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service:6] Unknown lvalue 'KillStop' in section 'Service'
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service:6] Unknown lvalue 'KillStop' in section 'Service'
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service:6] Unknown lvalue 'KillStop' in section 'Service'
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service:19] Unknown lvalue 'KillStop' in section 'Service'
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service:6] Unknown lvalue 'KillStop' in section 'Service'
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service:19] Unknown lvalue 'KillStop' in section 'Service'
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.
```

How can I remove nginx completely to recompile it from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have removed nginx. You have not removed the systemd unit file nor deactivated it.

To deactivate the service, run `systemctl disable nginx`. To remove the unit file, delete the file `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`.

Comment: Thanks a ton! After I removed the systemd file and restarted my server, I was able to recompile nginx.

Comment: You're welcome! For the future, some programs will have the option to run `make deinstall` or `make uninstall` from the source directory, which should remove all relevant files. This is up to whoever wrote the program, though.